# How can module know which article is displayed in com_content

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am developing a module that displays links to articles in a certain category.

Is it possible for the module to know which article (via article id?) is being displayed in the main component (com_content)? In this way, the module could exclude the article currently displayed from the list of article links in the module content.

Answer (score 0):

Using *JFactory* you can retrieve the current parameters of the page, in this case with this code:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$id = $jinput->get('id','','INT');
$view = $jinput->get('view','','STRING');
```

It gives you the view name, that should be *article* and the *id* of the article displayed.